# Show the congruence $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ has $p-1$ solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

**Question**: Let $p$ be prime. show the congruence $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ has $p-1$ solutions

**Attempt**: I know by Lagrange's theorem that this congruence will have at most $p-1$ solutions since $p-1$ is the order of the congruence

I know by Fermat's little theorem that if $(x,p)=1$ then $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$

I know I will have to combine Lagrange's theorem and FLT, but I cant see how there is exactly $p-1$ solutions

Comment: **Hint**: How many numbers $x$ from $0$ to $p-1$ satisfy $(x,p) = 1$?

Comment: I'd say that congruence has *infinite* many solutions... do you mean in the prime field $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ or *where* ?

Comment: @DarthGeek I must be quite tired, totally understand now, there are $p-1$ solutions, thanks

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood the question, but if x can be larger than or equal to p, this seems not to hold. eg. take $p=5$, $6^{5-1} \equiv 1$.

Comment: See http://math453fall2008.wikidot.com/lecture-23

Comment: @k99731 Take $p=5$, then we have solutions: $x=1,2,3,4$ so there are 4 solutions modulo 5. It holds. Also $6\equiv 1\pmod{5}$.

Comment: @Dansmith No, there are **also** the solutions $\;x=6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,-1,-2,-3,-4,-6,-7,...\;$ etc.

Comment: @Timbuc I just assumed by the context that we are working $\pmod{5}$

Comment: @Timbuc Of course, he must be talking about incongurent solutions, and in which its true :)

Comment: @DarthGeek Thanks for your answer, if you want to post a brief solution I'll award you the correct answer

Comment: @Dansmith There you go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are working in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

On the one hand, by Lagrange's Theorem, said congruence has at most $p-1$ solutuions

On the other hand, by Fermat's Little Theorem, if $(x,p) = 1$ then $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$.

Since the only element that does not satisfy $(x,p) = 1$ is $0$, then the remaining $p-1$ elements are solutons to the congruence.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{F}_p$ which is cyclic, we look at the morphism $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}\to \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$, $x\mapsto x^{p-1}$ and the kernel.

$Card\{x\in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times} \mid x^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p\}=\gcd(p-1,p-1)=p-1$.